# Using alternate resources with Build Flavors in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've read the official docs as well as several other questions on here, and no matter what I try my alternate resources never load. Please ELI5! If I have the following product flavor

```
productFlavor {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.packagename.flavor1"
    }
}
```

Where exactly do I create the alternative resource folder in my project hierarchy, and how exactly do I need to alter my build.gradle file so it knows to look in said location when building a particular flavor? The docs made this sound easy, but I've been trying different variations all afternoon with no luck whatsoever. What am I misunderstanding?

Edit: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    default_flavor {
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "default"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Android"

    }
    bengals {
        applicationId "com.example.Bengals"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "bengals"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Cincinnati Bengals"
    }

    bills {
        applicationId "com.example.Bills"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "bills"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Buffalo Bills"
    }

    boilermakers {
        applicationId "com.example.Boilermakers"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "boilermakers"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Purdue Boilermakers"
    }

    cardinals {
        applicationId "com.example.Cardinals"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "cardinals"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Cardinals"
    }

    colts {
        applicationId "com.example.Colts"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "colts"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Indianapolis Colts"
    }
    cyclones {
        applicationId "com.example.Cyclones"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "cyclones"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Cincinnati Cyclones"
    }

    eagles {
        applicationId "com.example.Eagles"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "eagles"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Philadelphia Eagles"
    }

    hawkeyes {
        applicationId "com.example.Hawkeyes"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "hawkeyes"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Hawkeyes"
    }

    hoosiers {
        applicationId "com.example.Hoosiers"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "hoosiers"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Indiana Hoosiers"
    }

    packers {
        applicationId "com.example.Packers"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "packers"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Green Bay Packers"
    }

    test_flavor {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "test"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Dolly Test"
    }

    titans {
        applicationId "com.example.Titans"
        resValue "string", "build_variant", "titans"
        resValue "string", "app_title", "Tennessee Titans"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile project(':admsAppLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile project(':Minimogrify')
    compile project(':urbanairship-lib-5.0.1')
}
```

Relevant section of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you created the folders in the right path.

It should be `app/src/flavor1/res`.

To make more sense your main resources are located in `src/main/res`.

Note: it's probably a typo but your code should say `productFlavors {` not `productFlavor {`

Comment: That's how I have it set up now, it seems to be working with my strings.xml but not the drawables folders. The structure looks like:

app/src/flavor/res/drawable/ic_launcher.png

But even though I have deleted all other alternate resources for ic_launcher from the project, all flavors still load with the default android icon instead of the custom assets I've provided in the flavor folders. Any insight into what could be going wrong there?

Comment: @swilkeni post your folder structure. Image would be nice.

Comment: @swilkeni Pieces of your real build.gradle too please.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question, build.gradle has been pasted into it

Comment: @swilkeni do you get an error, or the drawable is simply not used?

Comment: No error, the drawable simply wasn't used. Through some experimentation, I found making several drawable folders with the -*dpi tacked on the end solved the problem. I was under the impression a vanilla drawables folder would use the same resource for each density, but apparently was mistaken. Thanks for your help, you kept me on the right track!